# Change font size of the help tab/documentation in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

Is there a way to change the font size of the text shown in the `help` tab of `Rstudio`?

I know it's possible to change the font size in all panels at 
<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Global</kbd> >  <kbd>Options</kbd>  >  <kbd>Appearance</kbd> , but it doesn't change the font size in the `help` tab.

EDIT: I understand the answer will be OS specific. I'm personally using Windows but I'm sure others using a different OS would appreciate answers that address their needs as well

Comment: Answer is going to be OS specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holding down cntr/shift/(=/+) keys will make all Rstudio panels larger, including the help panel.  Use cntr/(-/_) keys to reduce.

If using 10 key keypad it is just control and either the + or the - key.

Note that these functions are independent of font setting that you listed in your OP. You can then change that font setting to down a notch or two after you get your help panel where you like it.

EDIT: based on a comment from @42- it appears that on a MAC, it would be the command with + or -.

Comment: The questioner didn't say what OS this was in. No need to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>-"+" (which didn't succeed for me.) Just <kbd>cmd</kbd>-"+" succeeds (as would be expected for an experienced mac user.) I suspect you didn't test this answer on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks @42-  I wasn't thinking about OS.

Comment: The only working solution as of January 2019. But also has the side effect of increasing the Options (opened via `Tools` > `Global Options...`) dialog box to such an extent that the `OK`, `Cancel` and `Apply` buttons move out of screen, if zoomed too much!

Answer (score 1):

You can go in **Tools** > **Global Options** > **General** > **Advance** tab > **Help panel font size**:
There you can set your preferred font size